# How do you call REST API resource unintentional field modifying?

Tags: web-application, vulnerability, api, rest

Today I stumbled on a potential vulnerability where I could change my profile rank. I'm pretty sure that should not be allowed for regular users.

Let's say, for example; I got an account profile endpoint:

```
https://example.com/api/account/profile/
```

For the HTTP **GET** request, the response looks something like this:

```
{
    firstName: 'foo',
    lastName: 'bar',
    rank: 1
}
```

Now I have an account settings page with a profile form where I can change my first & last name.

The updating request was using the HTTP **PATCH** method, and the body looks like this:

```
{
    firstName: 'foo2',
    lastName: 'bar2'
}
```

I tried to change the **PATCH** body to this:

```
{
    firstName: 'foo2',
    lastName: 'bar2',
    rank: 5
}
```

And it changed my rank too.

Now the **GET** request returns me this:

```
{
    firstName: 'foo',
    lastName: 'bar',
    rank: 5
}
```

I'm pretty sure I shouldn't be allowed to change my rank like this for that application.

My question is, is this a vulnerability after all, and if it is, what kind of or how do you call it?

Comment: welcome, it looks like it might be an oversight or a lack of clear specification - the 2021 owasp top-10 puts this at number 1, if you accept it is an example of "A01:2021 – Broken Access Control", viz. https://owasp.org/Top10/A01_2021-Broken_Access_Control/ and https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/

Comment: "Broken Access Control", great, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the correct vulnerability name is a **Mass Assignment** in the [OWASP API Security Project](https://owasp.org/www-project-api-security/).